# How to position inline blocks in a line relative to their previous one?

Tags: html, css

I am new to `CSS`.
I would like to know - if I have a row of `N` `inline-block` elements how do I position them relative to one another? I will autogenerate them and I will give an offset between them :

Example:

Given 6 elements with letting us say the offset of `3px`:

`1` [offset] `2` [offset] `3` [offset] `4` [offset] `5` [offset] `6`....`N`

How can I give the initial position to the first element in our case `1`  and the others would just take the offset and get next to their previous one?.

**HTML**

```
<div id="root" style="top:10px ;height:500;width:300">

<span id="space" style="position:relative;height: 16px;top:3px;display: inline-block;">spacing</span>

<span id="pic" style="position:relative;height:16px;width:16px;left:15px;top:3px;display: inline-block;">
  <img src="collapse.png">
</span>
<span id="pic2" style="position:relative;height:16px;width:16px;left:18px;top:3px;display:inline-block">
  <img src="collapse.jpg">
</span>
<span id="pic3" style="position:relative;height:16px;width:16px;left:21px;top:3px;display:inline-block">
    <img src="collapse.jpg">
  </span>
```

As you can see from the `CSS` above I have an initial element that serves as a spacing element. The `span`s that follow each has their `left` offset-ed by `3px` progressively. Can this be made automatically?
Can you just specify an `offset` and let them fall in line one by one?

Comment: You don't have to do inline style in every-line of the HTML. You should separate **HTML** and **CSS**. And then assign `class` on every span.

Comment: I know that i can create classes, but i want first to understand how do you make `N` spans continue one after another on the same line with a given `offset`in `px` between them.

Comment: I am not sure but are you looking for `margin-right: 3px;`.

Comment: 1) why do you use `spans` and not `div`?
2) Should all the elements be in an offset you define? or do you just wish they will have the same size of gap between them?
3) do all the elements have a fixed width?

Comment: inline-block itself by default takes 4px spacing. I think you are reducing 1px by declaring it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How can i give the initial position to the first element in our case **1** and the others would just take the offset and get next to their previous one?
Can this be made automatically?
Can you just specify an offset and let them fall in line one by one?

initial position to first element and others follow. irrespective of followers if the tag is same without any additional styling they tend to follow.

just by adding span in html the styles get applied.

yes that can be done, do not know if you insist upon inline style.

https://codepen.io/vssadineni/pen/zMpeqP

```
<style>
[data-root="true"] span{
  background:#cccccc80;
  padding:0.25em 0.5em;
  display:inline-block;

}
[data-root="true"] span:not(:first-child){
  margin-left:4px;
}
</style>
    <div data-root="true" id="root">
  <span>1</span>
  <span>2</span>
  <span>3</span>
  <span>4</span>
  <span>5</span>
  <span>6</span>
  <span>7</span>
  <span>8</span>
  <span>9</span>
  <span>0</span>
  <span>N</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you are looking for `margin-right: 3px;`

btw, `span` is an `inline` element. We don't use `span` to wrap an `image`.
Try using a `div` and set it to `display: inline-block;`.

https://codepen.io/blackcityhenry/pen/gQoZNy